# Issue with PHP curl / json POST

Tags: php, json, curl

I am running into an issue trying to issue a POST to the chargify API log payments from within a form.

However, it appears that the POST is actually being sent as a GET for some reason as it's returning an error.

Can anyone offer any advice on what I may be doing wrong? Postman is working just fine sending a POST with the JSON as the body, but I can't get it to work from PHP.

(note: the `<urlmaskedforprivacy>` is obviously not in my actual code)

```
    //find invoice id # using invoice number search form
    $invoiceNumber = fRequest::get('invoicenumber');
    $json = file_get_contents('https://<maskedforprivacy>.chargify.com/invoices.json?number=' . $invoiceNumber);
    $returnedInvData = fJSON::decode($json);
    $invoiceId = $returnedInvData[0]->invoice->id;


    // grab form data as payment info to send to chargify
    $paymentAmount = fRequest::Get('amount');
    $memo = fRequest::Get('memo');

    if ((isset($invoiceNumber,$paymentAmount,$memo))) {

    $url = 'https://<maskedforprivacy>.chargify.com/subscriptions/' . $invoiceId . '/payments.json';

    $params = array(
                      'payment' => array(
                           'amount'   => $paymentAmount,
                           'memo'    => (string)$memo
                      ),
                );

    // encode as json               
    $content = FJSON::encode($params);


    // send to chargify
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $status != 201 ) {
        die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
    }


    curl_close($curl);

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);      

    }
```

Comment: Please post the output you're getting.

Comment: Error 404. But i know the url is fine, as i can post to it no problem using postman and sending json in body

Answer (score 0):

I've used this one code, but it returns 401 error and asks for Basic auth. in json_response variable. May be you've missed it?

```
$paymentAmount = 10;
    $memo = 'test';



    $url = 'https://test.chargify.com/subscriptions/1/payments.json';

    $params = array(
                      'payment' => array(
                           'amount'   => $paymentAmount,
                           'memo'    => (string)$memo
                      ),
                );

    // encode as json
    $content = json_encode($params);


    // send to chargify
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $status != 201 ) {
        die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
    }


    curl_close($curl);

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
```

Comment: Auth is handled in the url using <key>:<pass>://chargify.com.... I just masked it out in my code for privacy.

Comment: Well - so the code almost as yours - I've removed header to see the answer in full mode, and no 404 error. Can you try the same and send full answer, otherwise I think it's impossible to help you.